# dyld isuess (Library not loaded)

Tags: ios, dyld

I have this message when I build my project:

dyld: Library not loaded:

```
@rpath/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework/Versions/A/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient
  Referenced from: /Users/dev01/mobile/ios/Test/test/testTests/FoneMonkey/bin/iphonesim
  Reason: image not found
```

This is dynamic link error and as I understand correct this error came because image not found. is this correct?

What steps should be taken to resolve errors?

I have found this [link](https://github.com/landonf/simlaunch/issues/8) and as I understad this error came because I use xcode 4.3. Now I have try this on 4.2 and everething work good.

But I not have any idea how to run it on XCode 4.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [dyld issues library not loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449468/dyld-issues-library-not-loaded)

Comment: I have the same problem with 5.1.  Not sure what it is. THe duplicate link did not fix the issue.

Comment: @nycynik I am using Xcode 5 right now

Comment: Are you maybe trying to load a library that doesn't support the simulator's arch?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have this problem after adding new library and you linked it in actual framework path, if you drag this library in embeded framework path then problem will solve. Another variant is that in build scheme you have enabled memory managment malloc, if you turn it off problem will be solved.

Comment: thank you for answer but it's old question that is connected to Xcode 4.3

Answer (score -1):

Check your SDK project settings (i.e. when passing from SDK 6.x to 7.x) maybe one of library was not compiled for architecture and project target. And the paths. Clean DerivedData and delete app from simulator (if it is there).
If you still need the Sdk just copy it from Xcode 4.6.(3) both for device and simulator and see if this solve your problem.