# RoboVM Error - dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: java, ios, maven, libgdx, robovm

I'm trying to use RoboVM with libGDX to run my game for the iOS. My project is built with maven and uses the maven robovm plugin to test the application in the iOS simulator. However, when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework/Versions/A/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient
[ERROR]   Referenced from: /Users/<user>/.m2/repository/org/robovm/robovm-dist/0.0.9/unpacked/robovm-0.0.9/bin/ios-sim
[ERROR]   Reason: image not found
```

I'm aware of both of these questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386731/dyld-isuess-library-not-loaded) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449468/dyld-issues-library-not-loaded), but one was never answered and the other's answer doesn't' seem to address my specific error.

I am running the following maven command to build and test the project:

```
mvn clean integration-test -Pios
```

And my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>[parent groupid]</groupId>
        <artifactId>[parent artifactid]</artifactId>
        <version>[parent version]</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>[artifactid]</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <mainClass>[Main Class]</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>[core groupid]</groupId>
            <artifactId>[core artifactid]</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdx-backend-robovm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>../assets</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${project.build.directory}/natives/</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.robovm</groupId>
                <artifactId>robovm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <config>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        <os>ios</os>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </config>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>iphone-sim</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>iphone-sim</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this error? I'm unfamiliar with both OS X and RoboVM, so I'm completely at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue should have been fixed in RoboVM 0.0.10. So change your pom to use the 0.0.10.1 version of the RoboVM Maven plugin and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Helped me only after I updated dependencies to 0.0.12.